# Can the apply function on a pandas dataframe produce a scalar?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I read the documentation on Pandas apply function which states that the apply function works on the rows or columns of a dataframe and returns a series or a dataframe. Is it possible to write the code in such a way that it returns a scalar? Or will it be necessary to further chain a .pipe function with it. I tried writing the following functions on a sample dataframe that has been provided in the documentation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
    'two' : pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
    'three' : pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), index=['b', 'c', 'd'])})

def my_func1(x):
    min_of_x = x[['one', 'two']]
    return min_of_x['one']

def my_func2(x):
    min_of_x = x[['one', 'two']]
    return min_of_x['one'].iloc[0]

def my_func3(x):
    min_of_x = x[['one', 'two']]
    return min_of_x.max()

def my_func4(x, elem_pos=0):
    return x.iloc[elem_pos]
```

When I run:

```
df.apply(my_func1, axis=1)
```

It works fine and gives me a Series as expected. But suppose I would like the first element or for that matter some calculation of the Series value that results in a scalar:

```
df.apply(my_func2, axis=1)
```

I get the error "AttributeError: ("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'iloc'", 'occurred at index a')". If I use my_func3 which calculates the max:

```
df.apply(my_func3, axis=1)
```

It works ok again returning a Series. The only way to return a scalar seems to be to chain another function using a .pipe:

```
df.apply(my_func1, axis=1).pipe(my_func4, 2)
```

So I just wanted to conclude whether the apply function produces only a Series or a DataFrame and any attempt to return another value produces this error. Would this be the case? This is just in case I wanted to run some calculation on the result which can't be done by in-built Panda and NumPy functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental thing to understand is that a `pd.Series` object is *always* passed to apply. What gets passed depends on what axis you call it with.

For example, `axis=1` will pass this:

```
one      ...
three    ...
two      ...
Name: a/b/c/d, dtype: float64
```

And, `axis=0` will pass this:

```
a    ...
b    ...
c    ...
d    ...
dtype: float64
```

In either case, this is a `pd.Series` object.

In `my_func1`, you slice the series like this: `x[['one', 'two']]` which also results in a series object. Indexing an individual item such as `x['one']` will return a *`float`* object, so it naturally makes sense that a float object will not have an `.iloc` attribute associate with it. This is why `my_func2` throws the `AttributeError`.

---

As an exercise, try running this code:

```
In [891]: def my_func1(x):
     ...:     print(type(x['one']))
     ...:     min_of_x = x[['one', 'two']]
     ...:     return min_of_x['one']

In [892]: df.apply(my_func1, axis=1)
```

This gives:

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But x['one'] returns a Series. In my_func1, the returned object is a Series with indices 'a','b','c','d'. So I was thinking it would be possible to extract a float out of this series with the .iloc[0] which is what I try to extend with my_func2.

Comment: @ShivKumar What makes you think that? Look at my answer, I've included an edit.

Comment: Thanks again. I ran the function. So when I use axis=1, I specify the function should use columns. And saying x['one'] after that causes it to decompose the column to a collection of floats. Is that what is happening? So when apply is used it is used either on columns or rows depending on whether axis=0 or axis=1. Does that prevent further extraction of individual columns or rows?

Comment: @ShivKumar If you use axis=0, you iterate over the rows, and can select elements by column. If you use axis=1, you iterate over columns and can select elements by row.